# A dynamic list/array which contains matrices and vectors

Tags: python

so I have the following setup. I have a folder with two different file types. One file type (.m) are files of matrices and the other file type are the corresponding vectors (.txt). They have the same name i.e. matrix1.m and matrix1.txt

I want to create a list or an array such that I can save each matrix and each corresponding vector. I thought about a panda data frame, but I do not know if this is useful here.

Is there a way to do this?

```
for file1 in os.listdir(path):
    file1name = os.fsdecode(file1)
    if file1.endswith('.m'):
        file2 = file1name.replace('.m', '.txt')
        file2name = os.fsdecode(file2)

        matrix = np.matrix(scipy.io.mmread(os.path.join(path, file1name)).toarray())
        vector = np.loadtxt(os.path.join(path, file2name)
        continue
```

Comment: Perhaps with numpy.save? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html?

Comment: The correct answer to this question depends on how you want to use this. a dict or array of tuples may be the right answer, or just a set of 'filename' strings with the extensions stripped, or... lots of them really. So- what are you going to do with the filenames?

Comment: @PaulBecotte I need to do several matrix vector operations. And it is about 200-300 matrices and vectors.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more? Do you need to load all the vectors to a matrix and then do operations? Do you need to do some set of transformations on each vector separately? is each pair of files a separate operation?

Comment: @PaulBecotte So for example, I read the first matrix and its corresponding vector. Then I do some operations with these two for example multiplication. The result is now saved in another file. Then I load the next matrix and its corresponding vector. Do the same operations and save this result also.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach something like this given-

I need to do and store some result for each pair of files
Each pair is independent
The reason the code above isn't enough is because you wanted to try and speed things up.

Don't know if this will help, but it is one approach.

```
pool = ThreadPool()
op_names = {name.split('.')[0] for name in os.listdir(path)}
def operation(name):
  matrix_filename = f'name.m'
  vector_filename = f'name.txt'
  return name, do_op(matrix_filename, vector_filename)

results = pool.map(operation, op_names)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it doesn't help me. Maybe I should answer the above questions to make it clear.